# Emailing from multiple brands

Tags: email, exchange

My company is planning on changing from having a singular brand to multiple brands going forward. Each employee could at any point in time be representing any one of the brands. But we also want mail to always appear as if it's coming from a team rather than an individual. I am trying to solve the issue of email sending/receiving/signatures in this scenario.

The more I can take the selection of mailbox/signature out of the users hands the better. We are using Microsoft Exchange 2010 but I am no exchange expert in any way, shape or form!

All mail will be sent via a 3rd party system that will know what brand it necessary for a particular email but it cannot append signatures dynamically, or alter the from address dynamically.

My idea is as follows:

- UserA (usera@company.com) in TeamA working for BrandA sends email from the 3rd party system
- Email gets 'TeamA-BrandA' inserted into the subject line before reaching Exchange
- Exchange detects subject line and inserts BrandA signature
  and also alters the from address to be teama@branda.com.

I was wondering if anyone has solved a similar set of issue before (it doesn't seem like it would be that uncommon) and what solutions did you use to do so? What problem were faced that I'm not foreseeing?

Does this solution seem feasible using Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exchange you can create Transport Rules.  One of these is to append "disclaimer text" to a message.  You can set the rule to run based on the condition that "TeamA-BrandA" is found in the subject line.  So you would be able to say when a message is found with "TeamA-BrandA" in the subject line, append this particular text to the message.  You have the option to reject the message if the text fails to append correctly.

To set this up via the Exchange Management Console (EMC):

1. Navigate to Organization Configuration > Hub Transport.
2. In the result pane, click the Transport Rules tab.
3. In the action pane, click New Transport Rule. On the Introduction page, complete the following fields:

   1. Name -   Type a name for the transport rule.
   2. Comment  - Optional
   3. Enable Rule  - New rules are enabled by default. If you want the rule to be created in a disabled state, clear the check box.
4. On the Conditions page, complete the following fields:

   1. In the Step 1. Select Condition(s) field:  Here is where you want to select `When the Subject Field Contains Specific Words.`

      1. **Click the 'Specific Words' and enter in the "TeamA-BrandA" (or other text)**.
5. On the Actions page, complete the following fields:

   1. In the Step 1. Select actions field, select the `append disclaimer text and fallback to action if unable to apply`.
   2. In the Step 2. Edit the rule description by clicking an underlined value field, complete the following fields:

      1. **Click disclaimer text. In the `Specify disclaimer` text dialog box, type the plaintext or HTML disclaimer text that you want to add to messages.**
      2. (Optional) To change the position of the disclaimer in messages, click append. From the Select position dialog box, select prepend.
      3. (Optional) To change the fallback action, click wrap. In the Select fallback action dialog box, select the desired fallback action.
6. On the Create Rule page, review the Configuration Summary. If you're satisfied with the configuration of the new rule, click New.
7. On the Completion page, click Finish.

You can then test by sending a message with the defined text in the subject field and verify that the entered text is appended to the message.

*Note*  There are currently known issues with Transport rules and Exchange 2010 SP3 Rollup 1.  There is a new Rollup 2 that corrects these problems.

Comment: Can you alter the from address with these rules too?